# How to hide bitnami banner in macOS

Tags: macos, command-line, executable, bitnami, .app

To hide the bitnami banner, google recomment to run

```
sudo ./bnconfig --disable_banner 1
```

But in **MacOS** it is **bnconfig.app** and so I am not able to run this. changing this to

```
sudo ./bnconfig.app --disable_banner 1
```

also failed.

*How can I do this in macOS*

[image]

Comment: Create an empty file at `/home/bitnami/banner/disable-banner` then do `sudo service bitnami restart`.

Comment: @marekful: My Path is /Users/juasoft/Documents/BITNAMI/odoo9

So in this case, where should I create the file and what the file name should be? Including the extension.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.app` folders on OS X are a bit peculiar. From the finder they look like programs, but in the terminal they are actually just folders.

It seems like this is the way to configure Bitnami on Mac: https://docs.bitnami.com/installer/components/bnconfig/

In your case I think that means:

```
~/Documents/BITNAMI/odoo9/apps/odoo/bnconfig.app/Contents/MacOS/installbuilder.sh --disable_banner 1
```

If you need to run this with `sudo`, replace the `~` with the absolute path to your home folder. You can get it with `(cd ~ && pwd)`.